# How do I retrieve video custom labels through the RestFB API using Java?

Tags: java, video, facebook-insights, restfb

I'm creating a java application that pulls data from facebook videos using RestFB. How can I retrieve the custom labels from each video?

Although I'm able to pull the normal data from each video, there doesn't seem to be any RestFB function that gets custom labels.

I've tried creating my own function by copying the RestFB source code for getting the title and then changing it according to the data I need, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `custom labels` field is missing atm in RestFB, so you can wait until a new version is released or write a custom video type like this:

```
public class CustomLabelsVideo extends Video {

   @Facebook("custom_labels")
   private List<String> customLabels = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<String> getCustomLabels() {
      return customLabels;
   }

   public void setCustomLabels(List<String> customLabels) {
      this.customLabels = customLabels;
   }
}
```

You need to use this type in the `fetchObject` method, and don't forget to add the `custom_labels` string to the fields you fetch.